# MySQL - UPDATE part of a string in a column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace some text in a column - text that I have confirmed exists. When I run the query:

```
SELECT Body FROM dbname.tcontent 
where body like '%http://local.website.org%'
and display=1
and approved=1;
```

it returns 359 records. So, I was expecting 359 records to be changed when I ran this query:

```
update dbname.tcontent 
set Body = replace(Body, 'http://local.website.org', '/foldername') 
where instr(Body, 'http://local.website.org') > 0 
and display=1 
and approved=1;
```

However, the query found 359 matches, but updated no columns. The message reads: "0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 359 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0. I'm pretty sure I've got the SQL correct as I've confirmed it from at least three sources. I have read that the 359 "matches" are based on records matching the WHERE clause, and so I believe the problem is with that second line:

```
set Body = replace(Body, 'http://local.website.org', '/foldername')
```

even though the SQL is correct. I've unchecked "Safe Updates" in my preferences just to be sure, and still, no rows are being updated.

I still think that maybe the slashes and/or dots in the text I am replacing are tripping up the replace method despite an example of doing what I want to do [here](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/).

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this query instead:

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`tcontent` 
SET `body`= REPLACE(`body`, 'FindThisText', 'ReplaceWithThisText') 
WHERE `body` like '%FindThisText%' AND `display`=1 and `approved`=1;
```

Always backup your table before running such UPDATE queries.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have added that I also tried that UPDATE statement. Same result: "0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 359  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0"

Comment: What if you try to update a single row? Can you do that?

Comment: I sure can: UPDATE table set SiteID = 'abc' where tcontentid = 'def' : "1 row(s) affected Rows matched:1 Changed:1 Warnings:0. Good thought, though. Thanks again for posting.

Comment: However, I cannot perform an UPDATE to one row using REPLACE, as follows: UPDATE dbname.tcontent set Body = REPLACE(Body, 'FindThisText', 'ReplaceWithThisText') where instr(Body, 'FindThisText') > 0 AND TCONTENT_ID = 12345;

Comment: @Andy that query worked for me in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41525/1). Are you sure there's a row that meets all of the criteria you need?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, I had to break it down into two statements. First Update statement replaced http:// with nothing, and the second replaced the remainder of the URL:

```
update database.tcontent set Body = replace(Body, 'http://', '')  where Body like '%http://local.website.org%';
update database.tcontent set Body = replace(Body, 'local.website.org', '/foldername')  where Body like '%local.website.org%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

Set Body = 'ReplaceWithThisText' ?

Comment: Hi kendra. That exact query (with a where clause)  works. The row is updated. However, when invoking the REPLACE method on the Body column to replace partial text that I know exists, no rows are updated :-(